# Editing crontab using bash script

Tags: bash, sed, cron

I have a list of crontab entries:

```
0 * * * * /home/tomcat/abc.sh
0 * * * * /home/tomcat/def.sh
```

I want to perform an action through a bash script and it requires one of the cron jobs to be disabled.

```
#0 * * * * /home/tomcat/abc.sh
0 * * * * /home/tomcat/def.sh
```

How can I comment a single cron job using bash script?

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's kinda dangerous in my book, I wouldn't recommend doing that. Instead, I'd update your script so that it creates a file (like /tmp/MY_SCRIPT_LOCK or whatever) at the start and removes the file at the end. Then just update the cron job so it doesn't run if it finds the file:

```
0 * * * * test -f /tmp/MY_SCRIPT_LOCK || /home/tomcat/abc.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a comment (#) at a particular line you can use -

Third line:

```
sed '3s/^/#/' filename
```

You can save this as new file or use output redirections.